# Find parent div in specific class name

Tags: jquery, html, parent

I have many different div name and each div have same div with the same class name.
Example :

```
<div class="block1-1">
    <div class="block1-11" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;background:url(images/thumb2.jpg) no-repeat;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-text">  <a href="#">COAL MINING</a>

                <p>PT. Jawon Abadi has several mining development projects in East Kalimantan, South Kalimantan and South Sumatra.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<a href="#"><img src="" class="img"/></a>-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block1-11">
    <div class="block1-11" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;background:url(images/thumb2.jpg) no-repeat;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-text">  <a href="#">COAL JETTY</a>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<a href="#"><img src="" class="img"/></a>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

etc.

I want to get `.block1-1` or `.block1-11` according to `.caption` class name.
Because i have many div, and i want to minimiza jquery code.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: and what you do when select `parent div` because you can do by many ways but it depend the condition let me know

Comment: @TheMechanic I want to add effect fadeIn() and fadeOut() to parent of `.caption`. Because its not effective if i code one by one for each parent div.

Comment: you can use `.parents()` or `.parentsUntil()` it will works check out this link http://api.jquery.com/?s=parents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **.parent** like

```
$('.caption').parent().attr('class');
```

and as you want the parent of that parent try with

```
$('.caption').parent().parent().attr('class'); //$('.caption').parents().attr('class');
```

or can try like

```
$('.block1-11 .caption').parent().attr('class');
```

Go through this link [**PARENT Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)

**EDIT**

```
    $('.block1-11 .caption').parent().fadeIn();
```

Comment: Hello, i just online. I just try, and it return parent div.
But i try to add in my code, it not work.
My code, is add fadeIn() fadeOut() effect to the parent that have `.caption` class

Thanks before for our answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.caption').parent().attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('.caption').parents().attr('class'));
```

will give result as `block1-11`

Answer (score 0):

try this

$(".caption").parents().attr('class');

try this parents() selector

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(".caption").closest("block1-11").attr("class");
```